# Inputs on left depends on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two inputs in div

Here is code

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;border-style:solid;border-color:#1d69b4;margin-top:25px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:70%;height:100%;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:30%;">
                <form>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;"/>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="From" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;"/>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But they floating to left because of div

I need them to be like this

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;border-style:solid;border-color:#1d69b4;margin-top:25px;">
    
        <div style="width:100%;height:30%;">
                <form>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;"/>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="From" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;"/>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But div need to be floating to left, how I can do this?

Comment: I can't see the difference. What is?

Comment: in first variant all divs float to left.

in second not@MoshFeu

Answer (score 0):

The elements are aligned left, but the containing div is not wide enough to hold them side by side.

Lets say you have 2 50% divs inside a 100% div, it will overflow due to a whitespace that's added.

Try addeding 'white-space: nowrap;' to the parent div:

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;border-style:solid;border-color:#1d69b4;margin-top:25px; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="float:left; width:70%;height:100%;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:30%;">
                <form>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;"/>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="From" style="padding: 12px 20px;margin: 8px 0;box-sizing: border-box; border-radius:50px;"/>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But It need to be70%

Comment: @Logan Hi, I see what you mean, I've updated the answer- try adding 'white-space:nowrap' to the parent div style

Answer (score 0):

> 1)You say container must be 70%,so,Can use `Media Queries` and change width's Text Box.
>
> 2)You use same name `ID` for Different two Element,this is Wrong.`ID` Name must be Unique, I change `lname` to Class name.

```css
.wrapper {
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:#1d69b4;
 margin-top:25px;
}

.container {
 float:left;
 width:70%;
 height:100%;
}

.frm {
 width:100%;
 height:30%
}

.lname {
 padding: 12px 20px;
 margin: 8px 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius:50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 653px) {
 .lname {
  width: 150px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 477px) {
 .lname {
  width: 50px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="frm">
                <form>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control lname" name="lname" placeholder="From">
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```